# Spell-checker in OSX not recognizing even basic English words

Tags: macos

Regardless of which application I use in mac OS (Sierra), even the most basic English words are not being recognized by the spell checker. Is there any way to "reset" the Dictionary in mac OS?

[image: spell check having issue with "precipitate"]

[image: spell check not recognizing "compliant"]

Comment: How is this question related to programming?

Answer (score -1):

Press command-shift-semicolon to get into the spelling checker preferences, and check if you have picked a language other than English.

If it's set to German, yes, then it won't recognise even basic English words.